# Data is not being stored in the database

Tags: php, mysql, database

My code is getting the ID from another, after I get that ID I will insert it to another table. The thing is it's not working, any idea why?

```
<?php 

session_start(); 
include("Connection.php");
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){  
    $name = $_POST['customerName'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO  `starbucks`.`orders` (
`ID` ,
`NAME` ,
`TOTAL_PRICE` ,
`TOTAL_ITEMS` ,
`TIME`
)
VALUES (
'' ,  '$name',  '', '',NOW())");

$_SESSION['user'] = $name; 
}
$dTime = time();
$myValue = isset($_REQUEST['dValue']) ?$_REQUEST['dValue'] : '';
echo "The time is: {$dTime}<br/>
The choice is {$myValue} ";

$sql = "Select * from product where NAME = '{$myValue}'";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $price = $row['PRICE'];
    $id = $row['ID'];
    echo $id;
    $sql2 ="INSERT INTO starbucks`.order_details (ID, ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_ID, QTY) VALUES ('', '', '$id', '1')";
   $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
}
?>
```

Comment: what's the single ` (back tick) doing in the query?

Comment: No, the way you substitute variables into your SQL string is very insecure.

Comment: @Dagon is right (and should write an answer instead of a comment).  The INSERT query has an imbalanced back-tick, which will prevent it from working.  You should check `mysql_error()` after you execute SQL statements!

Comment: Other are warning about SQL injection vulnerabilities in your code.  If you want to understand that advice, read my presentation [SQL Injection Myths and Fallacies](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies).

Comment: It's just a practice, our professor haven't teached us that yet soo please bear wtih me

Comment: You need to read @Bill's presentation.

Comment: Wait I already updated it , I am kinda rushing today due to lack of time and the deadline is today please help

Comment: This is now a new question, this should be a new stack overflow question. Incidentally, does your table contain 'customerName'?

Comment: I have set the `homework` tag.

Answer (score 3):

extra back tick in the INSERT, either add another or remove